# How do regular expressions work in htaccess to redirect an IP range

Tags: ip, redirection, links, htaccess, range

I've been trying to redirect an IP range from one link to another. I can do it for a single 256 address block:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^111\.111\.111\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /original_link/$
RewriteRule .* /new_link/ [R=301,L]
```

However, trying to block a 8192 address range (xxx.xxx.128.0 - xxx.xxx.159.255) requires regular expressions to express the redirect properly. Even though I found some examples, I couldn't make much sense of the values that have to be put in brackets. Can somebody please explain how to use those expressions properly?

My own attempt would look something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^xxx\.xxx\.1([2-5][8-9])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that would only match

```
xxx.xxx.128
xxx.xxx.129
xxx.xxx.138
xxx.xxx.139
xxx.xxx.148
xxx.xxx.149
xxx.xxx.158
xxx.xxx.159
```

What you want (if regexes is even the right tool; I'm not sure if there is a better way to match on netmasks that works here) would be

```
^xxx\.xxx\.1(2[89]|[3-5][0-9])
```

The parenthesised part matches **either** `2` followed by `8` or `9`, **or** `3`, `4`, or `5` followed by any digit.

You need the "any digit" in the second case, because otherwise the regex would match, for example, `xxx.xxx.13.57` which is not in your range.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. I think I get the logic now:

".1(2[89]" apparently means 128 AND 129, but why is there no minus between 8 and 9? Can it be left out for consecutive values?

The "|" apparently introduces the rest of the range. Now that I see the solution, it doesn't seem that hard :)

Thanks again :)

Comment: @Zerobinary99: The basic syntax is that `[blah]` matches `b` or `l` or `a` or `h`. If you want to match a whole _range_ of characters (according to ASCII ordering, or your locale's collation order if you're blessed with a fancy unicode-aware regexp engine), then you can just put the first and last character in the range, separated by `-`. So `[ad-gm]` is the same as `[adefgm]` and `[3-5]` is the same as `[345]`. You can write `[8-9]` if you want; it is the same as `[89]`.

Comment: I see. Let's see if I understood it completely. If I wanted to express the range xxx.xxx.0.0 - xxx.xxx.193.255, would the following expression be correct?

^xxx\.xxx\.(0|[0-1][0-9][0-3])

Comment: @Zerobinary99: No, that wouldn't match `xxx.xxx.114.99`, because the `4` is not matched by `[0-3]` (which matches only the digits `0`, `1`, `2`, or `3`). For that you would need something like `^xxx\.xxx\.([0-9][0-9]?\.|1[0-8][0-9]|19[0-3])` -- pretty monstrous, but regexes are not really made to do numerical ranges well.

Comment: That indeed is a monstrous line lol. I understand why my solution wouldn't affect the entire range, but I can't quite grasp the logic behind your solution. I can see that you start with a range of 0 to 10-99 and then apparently concatenate another range starting from 100-189 to 190-193. Correct? So it seems that "?\." is a way to concatenate several ranges within the same block. Can it be used multiple times within the same block?

Comment: @Zerobinary99: Not quite. The parenthesised block here consists of three parts, separated by `|`s. It matches anything that matches _one_ of the parts. The first part is `[0-9][0-9]?\.` which matches a digit, _perhaps_ followed by another digit (a `?` makes the thing immediately before it optional), followed by a full stop (a lone `.` has the special meaning of matching any single character, but `\.` matches just only a full stop). The second part is `1[0-8][0-9]` which matches 3-digit numbers from 100 through 189. The third part is `19[0-3]`, matching 190, 191, 192, and 193.

Comment: Now I get it :) Thanks a lot again for your patience. I accepted your answer and upvoted it :)