# Redirecting visitor with htaccess to another URL based on IP range

Tags: apache-http-server, redirection, htaccess

I've pored through other questions to find a solution, and the closest I've come is Zerobinary99's question here: [How do regular expressions work in htaccess to redirect an IP range](https://superuser.com/questions/856222/how-do-regular-expressions-work-in-htaccess-to-redirect-an-ip-range)

However, I'm not having luck. I can redirect a user from an IP range to another site completely, but I can't redirect a user to another page on my site. Here's what I have (this is a Wordpress site, btw - don't know if that matters):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^108\.196\.108\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /devops/$
RewriteRule .* /dev-ops/ [R=301,L]
```

However I still get mysite.com/devops when I navigate to that URL from the specified IP range, instead of being redirected to mysite.com/dev-ops.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Got it - I ended up with the following (including multiple ip ranges using [OR]) to redirect visitors in the specified ranges from the devops url to dev-ops:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^108\.196\.108\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^108\.196\.110\. [OR]
RewriteRule devops/ dev-ops/ [R=301,L]
```